# Ubuntu 16.04 linux-crashdump fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04

The Ubuntu 16.04 freeze by itself especially when 2-3 instance of Pycharm is actively running.I wanted to know the exact cause of the OS freeze and found `linux-crashdump`.
The `linux-crashdump` was installed using the link [kernel-crash-dump][1]
[1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html "kernel-crash-dump"

It states that after installation and rebooting the system

```
cat /proc/cmdline

BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.2.0-17-server root=/dev/mapper/PreciseS-root ro
 crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M
```

But `cat /proc/cmdline` is not showing the parameter `crashkernel` added to it.

I am not able to edit the /proc/cmdline in anyway.
If I add `crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M` then the error appears.

```
"/proc/cmdline" E667: Fsync failed
WARNING: Original file may be lost or damaged
don't quit the editor until the file is successfully written!
```

I am not able to move further, as per the documentation of kernel-crash-dump after the installation, I rebooted the system, but still the `crashkernel` parameter in the `/proc/cmdline` is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get completely what the problem was but as far as I understood you had problems with crashkernel. I think that it would help if you just remove it completely and reinstall it again, because you have lost some of the files of crashkernel and that's why it's not responding. Hope it helps :)

Comment: The problem is that the new ubuntu 16.04 is getting freeze after some time, that's why I wanted to know the exact reason for the system to get a crash.And while installing `linux-crashdump` and I am not able to get the report bcos the parameter `crashkernel` is not present in the '/proc/cmdline' as per the installation document is should be there.
I will try to uninstall it and then install it again. I hope my problem statement is clear.